# What is the best way to pass request attribute value in construct-arg

Tags: java, spring

I have bean. Whose constructor look like:

```
<bean class="com.thirdparypackage.SaticAppBuilder"
        id="app.builder.default">
<constructor-arg index="0" value="ABCD" />
<constructor-arg index="1" value="<Need to put a httpServelRequest Attribute value here" />
</bean>
```

I need to pass a request attribute value to index 1. What is the best way to achieve this?

Note:

- I don't own the code.So I can modify the class to take code from request object directly.

Use Case:
This class require data for particular applicaiton. The index 1 is the applicationId.

Stack:
Our stack look like

```
S1 ------ get data for app1 ----- <our server> --- we need to pass this data to this class. Which be later used by other class to fetch value. 
S2 ------ get data for app2 ----- <our server> --- we need to pass this data to this class. Which be later used by other class to fetch value.
```

Comment: Could you please share overall bean and explain why do you need to pass it?

Comment: You have to use the http requst only in the contoller layer(passing it to the other classes looks like a bad practice). So just pass `HttpRequest req` as parameter to any controller method, spring will inject it for you.

Comment: @Evgeni I don't own the code of this bean.It is third party package and which should not be get modified.

Comment: then post your use case.. what are you planing to do with this class

Comment: @Jaiwo99 Added more info in the question.

Comment: OK, it should be a data structure, so you don't need make it a spring managed bean at all. you can construct this object in controller and pass it.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't own source code of third-party bean you have to instantiate it in controller's method where `HttpServletRequest` will be injected as a parameter by Spring. Then pass required request attribute to constructor there.
In case you have accessor method provided by third-party bean you could autowire it in controller and then set required field by this accessor.

Comment: can't I create another bean where HttpServletRequest in injected and I call that's method in third party bean definition.

Comment: You can call method from bean and inject returned value to another via expression language but you can't just autowire HttpServletRequest type in a POJO. Again you have to instantiate it in controller and then inject to required bean but in that case you get a mediation object and this is an overhead I suppose